# How to calculate therical `mean`,`sd` based on given distribution paramters in R?

Tags: r, distributions, mean

Example: `gamma` distribution with `shape`=4,`rate`=0.05.

Checked [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution),In `gamma` distribution,`mean=shape*scale`.
As hundreds type of distribution, I cannot remember the formular of them.

Is there any function to calculate therical `mean` and `sd` based on distribution parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to do in R, since you’re not working with data. In fact, the software you might find most useful is WolframAlpha’s integral solver.

Remember that the theoretical (population) mean and standard deviation comes from expected values.

$$\mu_X=\mathbb{E}[X]$$

$$\sigma^2_X=\mathbb{E}[X^2]-(\mathbb{E}[X])^2$$

$$\sigma_X=+\sqrt{\sigma^2_X}$$

And then for continuous distributions like gamma, $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}g(x)f_X(x)dx$, at least for decent transformations $g$, which is where WolframAlpha might come in handy.

Or you can look up the equation for population mean and variance. These are given in standard references like Casella/Berger and will be available on Wikipedia.

Your exact combination of shape and rate can be plugged into equations on the Wikipedia page for the gamma distribution, resulting in $\mu=80$, $\sigma^2=1600$, and $\sigma=40$.

Comment: That you didn’t do that calculation, however, makes me wonder if you meant to ask a different question. Please clarify what confuses you.

Comment: gamma,betta,weibull,f,norm,lnorm,etc.I just use them in `fitdist(data,'name')`,I am lack of the basic knowledge about those distributions.At first I think R has some functions,when I key in `gamma`,output will be the basic formula  as WolframAlpha provide.

Comment: @kittygirl Do you see how I got 80, 1600, and 40 from the equations on the Wikipedia page?

Comment: Got it.Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @kittygirl I’m glad I could help but still don’t understand your question and am concerned that you may be making a mistake in your application of what you’re doing. Please describe in more detail what you hope to do.

Comment: I asked a easy question,nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The mean of a Gamma distribution is also $\dfrac{\text{shape}}{\text{rate}}$ and the standard deviation $\dfrac{\sqrt{\text{shape}}}{\text{rate}}$ so in your example a mean of $\frac{4}{0.05}=80$ and standard deviation of $\frac{\sqrt{4}}{0.05}=40$

Base R will not do the integration for you, but you can get a numerical approximation with something like

```
cases <- 10^6
values <- qgamma(ppoints(cases), shape=4, rate=0.05)
mean(values)
# 79.99999
sd(values)
# 39.99994
```

which comes close